# IntelliJ IDEA run logging behaves differently from sbt

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt, logback

I have a multi-project sbt build. The project is written in Scala. IntelliJ IDEA version is 14.1.5. Logging in tests is configured with `src/test/resources/logback-test.xml` in each sub-project. When I run a particular specs2 test in a sub-project with sbt, all the logging goes to `log/app.log`, as configured. However, when I run the test class from context menu in IDEA, some logging goes to IDEA console, and some -- to log file. The log records in IDEA console don't follow the pattern defined in `logback-test.xml`. Why is this happening and how can I make IDEA's behavior consistent with sbt?

EDIT: logging works as expected in IntelliJ with one `build.sbt` per project setup.